# setting max height among each three div elements and setting it to rest divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 10 floating element. In browser 3 divs will in row. I want to get max height of each 3 divs, and set it for all the divs present in that row.

can anybody help.

```js
(function(){
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("temp");
var ht = [];

for(i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
console.log("test :: ", x[i].clientHeight);
ht.push(x[i].clientHeight);
}
console.log("max :: ", Math.max.apply(null, ht));
var maximumht = Math.max.apply(null, ht);
$('div.temp').height(maximumht);
}())
```

```css
.temp {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="productwrap">
  <div class="tempwrap">
<div class="temp">some content</div>
<div class="temp">some content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="temp">some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have added what i had tried till now. I can able to get the max height among all the divs and apply that in all the divs. but my requirment is to get the max height of each three div present in the row and setting it among them

Comment: Is it an option to do it with pure css and display flex? I made a fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/Julesezaar/t7kge84f/5/

Comment: You don't need JS. Display flex does that out of the box. Three DIVs will have same height, the other three another height (max of the rows highest) and so on.

Comment: @Julesezaar, thanks for the comments, its working fine but its not adjusting the height if i resize the window (responsive). I need to refresh the page to get the height equal. Do you have any other idea on this.

Comment: @Raj , what browser are you using? I use Chrome and in my example the heights are responsive. I added extra text: https://jsfiddle.net/Julesezaar/t7kge84f/7/ Is there any extra javascript that overrules the css on your website? Can you make a fiddle of the exact problem? Because I can not reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Julesezaar, yes responsive is working fine but I have changed my code which is my real scenario. I have a div which is outside of other div. But i need to align that aswell. Can it be possible thru flex

Answer (score 0):

I made a new jsFiddle for that: https://jsfiddle.net/Julesezaar/bcgqz6x5/

```
var calculateHeights = function() {
    // reset heights before listing them again
    $('.tempwrap div.temp').height('');

    $(".tempwrap").each(function() {
        calculateHeightsInWrapper(this);
    });
};

var calculateHeightsInWrapper = function(wrapper) {
    var ht = [];
    $(wrapper).find(".temp").each(function() {
        ht.push(this.clientHeight);
    });
    var maximumht = Math.max.apply(null, ht);
    $(wrapper).find('div.temp').height(maximumht);
};

$(function() {
    // trigger one time on pageload
    calculateHeights();

    // trigger while window is resizing
    window.onresize = function(event) {
        calculateHeights();
    };
});
```